# URL in jquery ajax post in codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have some problem, 'query in views undefined'. How can I solve it ?

**Javascript**

```js
function search() {
  var query_value = $('input#name').val();
  if (query_value !== '') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: <?php echo base_url()?>
      "index",
      data: {
        query: query_value
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("table#resultTable tbody").html(html);
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
}
```

**javascript in views**

```js
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```

**link in html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/scripts/triggers.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. The second title is " _javascript in views_ " while it shows PHP code. Also, do you peform [`isset(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) call on the POST parameter before using that replacement method? And, if it's possible, can you add more details to the error message that you got?

Comment: What is your problem?